# Where clause in polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have the tables

```
threads
- id
```

```
replies
- id
- repliable_id
- repliable_type
```

I want to add another column to the **Thread**, which is the id of the most recent reply.

```
Thread::where('id',1)->withRecentReply()->get()
```

And the following query scope

```
public function scopeWithRecentReply() {
    return $query->addSelect([
            'recent_reply_id' => Reply::select('id')
                ->whereHasMorph('repliable', ['App\Thread'], function ($q) {
                    $q->where('repliable_id', '=', 'threads.id');
                })->latest('created_at')
                ->take(1),
        ]);
}
```

I have also tried

```
public function scopeWithRecentReply() {
    return $query->addSelect([
            'recent_reply_id' => Reply::select('id')
                ->where('repliable_id', '=', 'threads.id')
                ->latest('created_at')
                ->take(1),
        ]);
}
```

But in both cases the

```
recent_reply_id => null
```

If instead of **threads.id** i enter an integer, it works and the **recent_reply_id** is not null
For example

```
public function scopeWithRecentReply() {
    return $query->addSelect([
            'recent_reply_id' => Reply::select('id')
                ->whereHasMorph('repliable', ['App\Thread'], function ($q) {
                    $q->where('repliable_id', '=', 1);
                })->latest('created_at')
                ->take(1),
        ]);
}
```

My question is

Is there a way to be able to fetch the **recent_reply_id** using the respective **threads.id** ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `appends` instead of `query scopes` so in your `Thread` model we will add

```
protected $appends = ['recent_reply_id'];

.....

public function replies () {
    // you need to add here your relation with replies table
}

public function getRecentReplyIdAttribute () {
    return $this->replies()->latest('id')->first()->id;
}
```

now wherever you query the `threads` table you will have access to `recent_reply_id` like

```
$thread = Thread::where('id',1)->withRecentReply()->get();

$thread->recent_reply_id;
```

Comment: Actually, i need the id in the query scope because i want to continue building the query, because the query i want to create is a little bit more complex than just fetching the id.